# How to bring the caption of a figure below the word "figure" NOT the image of the figure

Tags: floats, captions, subcaption, bold, apa-style

[image]I have been trying to make the word "Figure" bold and bring the caption underneath the word "Figure", not the image. I don't know if I can make myself understood but I don't want to write the caption under the figure. Because the word **Figure** should be bold in APA and the caption should not be in front of the semicolon but underneath it.
I attach a screenshot of what I mean.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You might want to give us a minimal compilable example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're employing a document class that's compatible with the `caption` package, the following instructions, to be run in the preamble, should let you achieve your caption-realted formatting objective.

```
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf, textfont=it, labelsep=newline,
              singlelinecheck=false}
```

A full [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) and its output:

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf,textfont=it,labelsep=newline,
              singlelinecheck=false}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} % just for this example

\begin{figure}
\caption{Finsec's Communication Networks}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```